# why shapefiles created with sf package do not display same CRS in ArcMap?

Tags: r, esri, rgdal, r-sf

I have created a polygon shapefile in ArcMap using 7 points(lat,lon) then read this shapefile into R to obtain the CRS. I then created a shape file in R using the sf package (and the 7 points) and used the CRS obtained from the ArcMap shapefile. When i bring the shapefile created in R into ArcMap i get a warning regarding different coordinate systems. Why would this happen??

My steps:

1. 7 points (lon and lat) where point 1 = point 7 (closed loop). Create a polygon shapefile in ArcMap and display. Properties in ArcMap show :
   Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
   Datum:  D_North_American_1983
2. In R i use rgdal to read in shapefile and obtain CRS

```
cashes <- rgdal::readOGR(dns="path",layer="shapefile") 
cashes@proj4string
```

This results in : "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 "

3. Now i create the shapefile in R using the sf package (i could use %>%)

```
Rshapefile <- readxl::read_xlsx(path,sheet="cashes")
Rshapefile <- sf::st_as_sf(Rshapefile,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs="+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 ")
Rshapefile <- dplyr::summarize(Rshapefile,geometry = sf::st_combine(geometry))
Rshapefile <- sf::st_cast(Rshapefile,"POLYGON")

sf::st_write(Rshapefile,dns=path,layer="Rshapefile",driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

I then bring this Rshapefile into ArcMap and the cordinate systems are different. When i view the properties in ArcMap they show:
Geographic Coordinate System:   GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)
Datum:  D_unknown

why is this? I must be doing something wrong but i can't figure out what!

Comment: Maybe ask this in here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/